# Text has no element

Tags: html, css

Trying to include a PHP-file from a weather station into my page.

However it does not work like I want.

The weather station sends out an XML-file witch can't be changed, so I need to make changed in the CSS-file, if that's possible. I want to add a linebreak or something, to make it look good. But the text does not have an element...

I have managed to take control over the images with:

```
#weather.four.columns img {
float: left;
clear: left;
width: 20px;
height: 20px; }
```

The webpage can be found at: http://minerva.hivolda.no/~oleav/eksamensandkasse

Any suggestion?

Comment: You should simply consider the XML response as a source of data, then use this source of data whether server-side or client-side, parse it and generate appropriate HTML (+CSS)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#weather.four.columns img {
float: left;
clear: left;
display:inline-block;
width: 20px;
height: 20px; }
```